# Why is timeout bad as a top level middleware?

Tags: node.js, http, express, connect

The timeout middleware : https://github.com/expressjs/timeout#api seems useful to have to timeout for hanging  http requests.

However the middleware documentation mentions it's bad to use it as a top-level middleware (https://github.com/expressjs/timeout#api)

> NOTE This module is not recommend as a "top-level" middleware (i.e. do not recommend for use as app.use(timeout(5000))).

Any idea why? Makes me wonder if it should be used at *any* level at all.

Comment: My first guess would be that it would interfere if someone were trying to download a large static file from your site.  So instead of doing `app.use(timeout(5000)))`, you should give a prefix that you want long requests to timeout on, such as: `app.use('/api', timeout(5000)))`.

Comment: it will stop the request flow on a timeout. but why? if we have not done anything and have not checked down the server (stream)?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by dougwilson here : https://github.com/expressjs/timeout/issues/9#event-129212094

> Because of the way middleware processing works, once this module passes the request
>    to the next middleware (which it has to do in order for you to do work), it can no longer
>    stop the flow, so you must take care to check if the request has timedout before you
>    continue to act on the request.